# JList data addition for IF statements

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist

I know this is kind of a beginners question but my books aren't explaining it and the API isn't helping much when I don't understand it. Someone please help me to get this.

I created a `JList` using NetBeans and everything is set to whatever NetBeans has as a default for `JList`s.

My goal is to make a `JList` show a List of [x] if a user picks "blah" out of a `JComboBox`.

I've gotten to use an `ActionListener` on the `JComboBox` but I'm not quite sure on how to add or remove items from a `JList`, so my question is:

In simple terms, how would I go about coding a way to add and remove from a `JList`?

Help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans generates a `JList` with a simple model:

```
jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
    String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
    public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
    public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
});
```

The values of this model cannot be changed afterwards.

---

You can either create a new model when you need to change the values, or declare your own model:

```
private DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
```

and change the `model`-property of your `JList` to `Custom Code`, and enter the name of your model (`listModel`), so that the generated code looks like this:

```
jList1.setModel(listModel);
```

[jList1 [JList] - model http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/38/sojlistmodelnetbeans.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/38/sojlistmodelnetbeans.png)

With this model you can then call [`add`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#add%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) (or [`addElement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement%28java.lang.Object%29)) or one of the `remove*`-methods:

```
listModel.addElement("Test");
```

---

Make sure to read the Java Tutorial [How to Use Lists](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks :D gonna try it out and see if it works...I seriously had no idea how to work with them :\

Comment: @Kitsune About how models work. Here is a very good overview of Swing architecture: [A Swing Architecture Overview](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/)